# Preimage of a function ...

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Given a function $f: \mathbf{N}_0 \to \mathbf{N}_0$, defined
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+3 & \text{if } x \in \mathbf{N}_{\text{even}} \\
x-1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbf{N}_{\text{odd}}
\end{cases}
$$

How can I find the preimage $f^{-1} ({1,2,3,4})$ ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Compute the first values of $\{ f(x) \mid x \in \mathbb N_0 \}$ and compare them with $1,2,3,4$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what does "compute" mean?

Comment: Just to elaborate: say you take the number $x=5$, then $f(5)=5-1=4$ and so IF this is the only $x$ that $f$ takes to 4, then we say the preimage $f^{-1}\lbrace 4\rbrace=\lbrace 5\rbrace$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+3 & \text{if } x \in \mathbf{N}_{\text{even}} \\
x-1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbf{N}_{\text{odd}}
\end{cases}$$ we get that odd numbers map to even numbers and even numbers map to odd numbers.

Since $f(x)=1$ is odd, $x$ is even. Thus $$f(x)=x+3=1$$ Thus the pre-image of $1$ does not exist in $N$

Similarly we find $$f^{-1}(2)=3, f^{-1}(3)=0 ,    f^{-1}(4)=5.$$ Therefore,$$ f^{-1} ({1,2,3,4})=(?,3,0,5)$$

Comment: The preimage of $1$ does not exist; $f$ is defined only on $\mathbf{N}_0$.

Comment: Mind you that $f:\mathbb{N}_0\to \mathbb{N}_0$, so we need to interpret $f^{-1}\lbrace 1\rbrace$ differently.

Comment: Thanks , I fixed my error.